# Can't use Emacs IPython Notebook?

Tags: ipython, ein

I've never tried IPython Notebook so I thought I would try EIN.

I installed `ipython` via `dnf` on `Fedora 23` with all of the dependencies.

Then I installed `ein` via `M-x list-packages` through `elpa`.

But when I added `(require 'ein)` to my `init.el` I am getting the following error running emacs with `--debug-init`.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot $
  require(ein)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/myusername$
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/myusername/.ema$
  load("/home/myusername/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "^H\205\262^@     \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\2$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

I'm not sure what to look into to help me debug this. I saw a few compilation errors during installation of `ein` with `elpa` but when I relaunched and looked at `M-x list-packages` then it says it is installed. Is that somtehing I should be worried about?

Comment: You do not need to `(require 'ein)`.  Instead you should `(package-initialize)`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the line should be

```
(require 'ein)
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry that was pseudocode. I had that in my `init.el`. I'm going to go ahead and try `ob-ipython` because apparently it has better integration with `org-mode` anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This works out of the box with [the new package](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook) on Emacs 25 and above.

> ## Usage
>
> 1. Install from [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/)*.    For manual install, put Emacs lisp `ein*.el` files and Python file    `ein.py` in your load path. See
>      `online documentation`* for more    information.
> 2. Start the [`Jupyter notebook server`](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content-quickstart.html).
> 3. (Optional) Newer versions of Jupyter have token [authentication](http://blog.jupyter.org/2016/12/21/jupyter-notebook-4-3-1/)_ enabled by default so you will need to call `M-x ein:notebooklist-login` and enter the    token as the password.
> 4. Execute `M-x ein:notebooklist-open` to open notebook list.